# watin - add a text to a <div>

Tags: watin

I have found a site with a `<div>` field containing an editable text. I can isolate my `<div>`, but I can't find any method to add a text field there (tried AppendText, Text, TextField and any other I could think about).

How can I insert my text?

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to hack a website

Comment: WatiN is a web-apps testing framework. It mustn't provide ability to modify source web-page. Why are you needs in it? Is i'm right, you want to add <input /> to the page?

Comment: Are you implying that there is a textfield that has text in it and you wish to add some of your text on top of the text that is already present?

Comment: @AdrianCornish: This could be a genuine test requirement, not necessarily a hack. Many client-side controls that allow users to edit formatted text use `<p>` or `<div>` element's `InnerHtml` to display those contents. So if you want to automate putting contents into those fields, WatiN is of no help as far as I'm aware. @OCray's answer below doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

This was answered on the WatiN mailing list with the fololwing:

```
.SetAttributeValue("Innerhtml", "text to be inserted")
```

I have not tested the above.